# Raft: how can I do some recover work when a node broke down?

Tags: go, distributed, distributed-computing, consensus, raft

Recently I'm writing a distributed system using hashicorp/raft package, each node of the system will do a part of the whole work. When a node broke down, its working results will be lost,then I need to let other nodes rerun its work. But hashicorp/raft doesn't provide any API to add a callback, how can I do ?

Comment: You want a callback for when a node is lost?

Comment: Yes. I want to do something when a node is lost.